# Show that $\frac{\cos \frac{1}{x}}{x^2}$ is not integrable on $(0,1)$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\Omega=(0,1)$. How to prove that the function $$f(x)=\frac{\cos(\frac{1}{x})}{x^2}$$ is not Lebesgue integrable in $\Omega$ ?

Comment: I think that we must use the dominated convergence Theorem.

Comment: the $f_{n}$ are increasing to $f$ so it's MCT I think.

Comment: the $f_n$ is not non-negative, so MCT can not be applied in this case. And I am not sure that the $f_n$ is increasing.

Answer (score 2):

Since

$$\cos(x) \geq \frac{1}{2} \qquad \text{for all} \, \, x \in \left[-\frac{\pi}{4}+2k\pi,\frac{\pi}{4}+2k \pi \right], k \in \mathbb{N},$$

we have

$$\cos \left( \frac{1}{x} \right) \geq \frac{1}{2} \qquad \text{for all} \, \, x \in \left[ \frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{4}+2k\pi}, \frac{1}{-\frac{\pi}{4}+2k \pi} \right] =: A_k.$$

Thus,

$$\begin{align*} \int \left| \frac{\cos \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)}{x^2} \right| \, dx &\geq \sum_{k \geq 1} \int_{A_k}  \left| \frac{\cos \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)}{x^2} \right| \, dx \\ &\geq \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k \geq 1} \left( \frac{1}{-\frac{\pi}{4}+2k \pi}\right)^{-2} \lambda(A_k) \\ &=   \frac{\pi}{4} \sum_{k \geq 1} \left(- \frac{\pi}{4} + 2k \pi \right)^2 \frac{1}{4\pi^2 k^2 - \frac{\pi^2}{16}} = \infty \end{align*}$$

using

$$\lambda(A_k) = \frac{1}{-\frac{\pi}{4}+2k\pi} - \frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{4}+2k\pi} = \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{1}{4 \pi^2 k^2 - \frac{\pi^2}{16}}.$$